# Can I force a UL to be OL?

Tags: html, feedburner

I'm trying to style my feedburner buzzboost html version of my rss feed. Consequently I cannot change the classes used to style the appearance so I wondered if it is possible to force the UL to be a numbered list (OL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the CSS stylesheet: put "list-style-type: decimal" on your UL.